# Problem with upgrading rubygems via rvm

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, rvm

Trying to updgrade RubyGems to version 1.8.10 via RVM and this error:

```
$ rvm rubygems latest
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-1.8.10 for ruby-1.9.2-p180 ...
ERROR: Error running 'GEM_PATH="/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180:/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global:/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180:/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global" GEM_HOME="/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180" "/Users/foo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby" "/Users/foo/.rvm/src/rubygems-1.8.10/setup.rb"', please read /Users/foo/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p180/rubygems.install.log
WARN: Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully.
```

When checking the log file (rubygems.install.log) this is generated from installation:

```
[2011-09-27 21:16:57] GEM_PATH="/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-
p180:/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global:/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180:/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global" GEM_HOME="/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180" "/Users/foo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby" "/Users/foo/.rvm/src/rubygems-1.8.10/setup.rb"
unable to convert U+00E1 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/rubygems/package/f_sync_dir.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+00E1 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/rubygems/package/tar_header.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+00E1 to US-ASCII in conversion from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+00E1 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/rubygems/package/tar_output.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+00E1 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/rubygems/package/tar_reader/entry.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+00E1 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+00E1 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/rubygems/package/tar_writer.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+00E1 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/rubygems/package.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+0160 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for History.txt, skipping
unable to convert U+00E1 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/rubygems/package/f_sync_dir.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+00E1 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/rubygems/package/tar_header.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+00E1 to US-ASCII in conversion from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+00E1 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/rubygems/package/tar_output.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+00E1 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/rubygems/package/tar_reader/entry.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+00E1 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+00E1 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/rubygems/package/tar_writer.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+00E1 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/rubygems/package.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+0160 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for History.txt, skipping
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RDoc::Error)
    error generating index.html: Error while evaluating /Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rdoc-3.9/lib/rdoc/generator/template/darkfish/index.rhtml: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (RDoc::Error)
RubyGems 1.8.10 installed
```

Does anyone have an idea of ​​what could be wrong with the update? Have tried to remove rubygems via the RVM also, and then run the update again but no luck with it.

**Update:** Seems like rvm could not run Ruby 1.9.2.

```
$ rvm use 1.9.2 WARN: ruby ruby-1.9.2-p290 is not installed. To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p290'
```

So after installing 1.9.2-p290 the installation of rubygems completed successfully.

```
$ rvm use 1.9.2
Using /Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290

$ rvm rubygems latest
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-1.8.10 for ruby-1.9.2-p290 ...
Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Seems like rvm could not run Ruby 1.9.2. $ rvm use 1.9.2
WARN: ruby ruby-1.9.2-p290 is not installed. To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p290' So after installing 1.9.2-p290 the installation of rubygems completed successfully.

Comment: You should either delete your question or post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Andrew Marshall: I know, seems like it takes 48 hours before I can mark my own answer as a solutions? So wait you'll see. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like rvm could not run Ruby 1.9.2.

```
$ rvm use 1.9.2 
WARN: ruby ruby-1.9.2-p290 is not installed. To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p290'
```

So after installing 1.9.2-p290 the installation of rubygems completed successfully.

```
$ rvm use 1.9.2
Using /Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290

$ rvm rubygems latest
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-1.8.10 for ruby-1.9.2-p290 ...
Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by removing this file .gemrc in root

```
cd ~
rm .gemrc
rvm rubygems latest
```

Comment: I don't understand why this worked, but it did.  Problem solved.  My error log was different than GLindqvist's, but same RVM error.